# Index out of range after item has been deleted from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row

Please help me find what is my mistake. I have a table view the data source is an array called items. After one item has been deleted from the items array the cellForRowAt method called and the parameter indexPath.row is equals with items.count. This happens only, when the rows count is just enough to one item is out of the table view's view. 
When it happens it cause a fatal error (index out of range). A hack is used in this case and the value of the IndexPath.row be decreased.

Please see the following image:

[image]

The following code for cellForRowAt:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    var i = indexPath.row
    if i >= items.count { i = items.count - 1 } //XXX: hack! Sometimes called with indexPath.row is equal with items.count :(
    cell.set(items[i])

    return cell
}
```

And the following code for the delete:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete)
    {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
    }
}
```

**I think is not relevant, but I'm using iOS 11.0**

**UPDATE**

I tried, and the following very simple code is also affected:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var items = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(items[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete)
        {
            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        }
    }
}
```

How to reproduce:

1. Scroll to down to Y be the last item on your screen

[image]

2. Try to delete Y swiping to the left

[image]

3. And getting the following error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your "hack" in `cellForRowAt` shouldn't be there. If you actually need it then you have a problem in your `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: My numberOfRowsInSection returning with: return items.count

Comment: try reloading your tableVew `tableView.reloadData()` after you delete the row(item as index in `items`) so that numberOfRowsInSection is updated from the new items.count

Comment: I tried before posting but got the same error. :( But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your deletion code looks fine, but you should not do what you´re doing in your `cellForRowAt`. Do it like this instead:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
    cell.set(items[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

And your `numberOfRowsInSection` should be like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
```

**Update:**
We just confirmed that this was a bug related to Xcode 9 beta and iOS 11. Working fine on Xcode 8.x. OP will file a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple regarding this.

Comment: My numberOfRowsInSection is same as you mentioned. This is why I don't understand what is the problem. Has no other thread so the items array couldn't be modified by another way.

Comment: @EdmundElmer, if you do it as I have in my answer and it´s still not working then you have something else in your code that´s not working. Add more code to the question so that we can continue the investigation.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to cut out all the not necessary and not problem-related code and I will post the whole controller code. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I tried with a simple as possible view controller, but I got the same error. :(

Comment: @EdmundElmer, just tried out your code and it´s working for me... [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjojucnt5gkq6vw/SO.zip?dl=0) is my project combined with your code try it out.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I got the same error! I'm using iOS 11 on my iPhone 7 and also using iOS 11 on iPhone SE simulator and got the error on both :( Could be something iOS11-related problem?

Comment: I tried your code and worked fine (like mine), so it seems to me something iOS11 beta related bug :(

Comment: I just tried on Xcode 9 beta, with iOS 11 and my project is working fine.

Comment: Thank you so-so much for your help! I don't know what is going on here. I'm going investigating what is the problem. Did you try the mentioned element? Because the bug comes, when the last out of view element need to be the last in view element.

Comment: @EdmundElmer, you can join me in [this](https://appear.in/stackoverflow) AppearIn video conference and I´ll try to solve your issue there if you need my help I´ll be in there.

Comment: After i delete cell, my app crash: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'"
But, this just happen sometime when I delete cell from middle, and work fine if I delete from first or last cell. And I can't find any problem.
I use ios 11, xcode 9